# Как развернуть MySQL дамп размером 700mb на Debian?

Tags: debian, mysql

Удаленные клиенты выдают Out of memory.

В конфиге MySQL поставил `max_allowed_packet` = 800M. На сервере стоит Debian, как с консоли развернуть дамп?

Answer (score 1):

Sql dump splitter помог, можно закрывать